# javascript not working textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add things to a textarea.  it's not working...

```
<html><head></head><body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="leftc">
text here 
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: $('wrapper').$('rightx').$('thebox').value += 'TEST\ntest\n\ntest">Add</a>
</div>
<div id="rightx">
<textarea id="thebox" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT: SOLUTION I USED:** (Thank you all for insight into my errors)

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('thebox').value += 'TEST\ntest\n\ntest';">Add</a>
```

Comment: Since you've included the html/head tags, I'm guessing this is your complete markup? Where is the reference to jQuery?

Comment: Do you have a Firefox Gold account? It includes a console which logs errors in your code. It's super useful.

Comment: @Brandon, No jquery.  This is all I have.  I'm looking for a javascript only solution if possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This piece of code makes no sense and is full of errors:

```
$('wrapper').$('rightx').$('thebox').value += 'TEST\ntest\n\ntest
```

The proper jQuery code would be:

```
$('#thebox').get(0).value += 'TEST\ntest\n\ntest';
```

Or, this might even be more straightforward in plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById("thebox").value += 'TEST\ntest\n\ntest';
```

You had the following errors:

1. Quote mark errors
2. Invalid and unnecessary chaining of multiple independent jQuery calls.
3. .value is not a jQuery method (it's a DOM method)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're mixing traditional javascript with jquery.  Simply in jQuery you can do this

```
$('#thebox').val($('#thebox').val()+"TEST");
```

As a point you're also missing the end quote in the test string at the end on your example.

Also, If you're not using something like the Chrome debugger or Firebug in Firefox I suggest you use a browser that can output some of these simple errors.  It will save you a lot of time and frustration seeing JavaScript errors in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because it's pretty much all wrong :-)

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#thebox')[0].value += 'TEST\ntest\n\ntest'">Add</a>
```

There's no point walking down the DOM by "id" values because "id" attributes need to have globally-unique values anyway. Thus, the only "id" you need to worry about is the one on the `<textarea>` element itself.

Answer (score 0):

You would just need `$('#thebox').val('test');`

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in that, I had skipped the `#`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html><head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script></head><body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="leftc">
    text here 
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript: $('#thebox').val($('#thebox').val() + 'TEST\ntest\n\ntest')">Add</a>
  </div>
  <div id="rightx">
    <textarea id="thebox" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Why use `#wrapper #rightx #thebox` as the selector instead of `#thebox`?  The latter is significantly faster and just as accurate.

Comment: You are correct jfriend00, I just edited the code quickly. Edited again ;)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can try closing the `'TEST\ntest\n\ntest` string with an additional `'`.

Comment: Yes that's important. However the entirety of the rest of the handler is wrong too :-)